# DHCP Lease time

Tags: internet, dhcp, ip

I have computer connected to internet directly.
But once every hour IP changes and I do not want that for sure.
How can I set IP lease time for like a year or so?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You don't control this. Lease time is set by the DHCP servers of your ISP.

You can try calling them and asking for a static address. Some ISPs will accommodate you for a small fee.

Comment: Howcome with connected router to modem IP was the same for like a year?

Comment: @DanSpd - Your internal IP was the same because that was handled by your router, your external IP (the one used by the router's WAN interface) most likely changed just as frequently. This was transparent to you.

Comment: Actually my WAN ip was the same for one year with router installed. And I am pretty sure about that.

Comment: @DanSpd - Then there was a change in your ISP that just happened to coincide with you getting rid of your router. There is absolutely no way for a client to influence lease time from a DHCP server, whether that client be a router or a computer.

Comment: There were no changes from ISP. I think someone else (other than you) will be able to help more because there should be a way to change lease time since router was able to hold it for a year.

Comment: @DanSpd - How can you say for sure that there were no changes at the ISP? Do you work there? I run 6 DHCP servers, 4 Windows, 2 Unix that service over 2000 clients daily. Trust me when I say that a DHCP lease is defined on the server and there is nothing a client can do to influence it.

Comment: >_> I just plugged in router into modem
And did like 5 modem restarts and so far ip wasnt changed.
explain that

Comment: @DanSpd - You said it happens once an hour. That leads me to believe that the DHCP lease is 1 hour long. That means that no matter how many times you power cycle your router, it will continue to get the same address for the duration of the lease (1 hour). You may want to read this http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2131.txt

Comment: ok I will wait hour, two, day and I am 100% sure IP will not change.

Comment: If you're on Windows, open a command prompt and type ipconfig /all this will show you the Lease obtained/Lease expires times for your interfaces.

Comment: @Pulse - You're right, but you should note that this is only valid if his computer is directly connected to the Internet, otherwise he will see the lease info from his router.

Answer (score 0):

What is your operating system?  What is your network configuration settings?
If you put the router back between the computer and the modem do you have an IP which lasts longer than an hour?

This is really odd, the only thing I can think of is if for some reason your computer was releasing and renewing with a new IP address every hour.  You can do this by ipconfig /release and /renew.  Check if releasing and renewing gives you a new IP on demand.  It does then it's a configuration issue on your computer, just stick the router back in front and you will be fine (as the release renew will get intercepted by the local DHCP server).

Comment: Windows Server 2003 Enterprise 64bit
If router is connected to modem then IP will stay the same as long as I do not restart modem like 2-3 times or even more. If computer will be connected via router then IP will lost as long as I don't restart modem few times, as I said before.

Release/renew commands change IP

Comment: Well it looks like for some reason your computer is releasing the IP lease on purpose then.  You likely have something configured wrong, some sort of timeout meant to keep the server up and avoid ip conflicts (assuming it is behind a router) in case anyone using DHCP or static IP assumes your IP.  
I can't say for certain what it is because I'm not a server guy, you might want to try serverfault.com